# Не стартует Mysql

Tags: mysql, debian

Сегодня утром Обвалился mysql, причем сервер я даже не трогал, он только прислал сообщение

> 2016-09-05 01:00:06] ERR [panel] SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1021 Disk full (/tmp/#sql_5870_0.MAI); waiting for someone to free some space... (errno: 28 "No space left on device"):
>
> 0: /opt/psa/admin/externals/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:234
>           Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(array)
>
> 1: /opt/psa/admin/externals/Zend/Db/Statement.php:300
>           Zend_Db_Statement->execute(array)
>
> 2: /opt/psa/admin/externals/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php:479
>           Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query(string 'DESCRIBE `locales`', array)
>
> 3: /opt/psa/admin/externals/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php:238
>           Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query(string 'DESCRIBE `locales`', array)
>
> 4: /opt/psa/admin/plib/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php:19
>           Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query(string 'DESCRIBE `locales`')
>
> 5: /opt/psa/admin/externals/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php:169
>           Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->describeTable(string 'locales', NULL null)
>
> 6: /opt/psa/admin/externals/Zend/Db/Table/Abstract.php:835
>           Zend_Db_Table_Abstract->_setupMetadata()
>
> 7: /opt/psa/admin/externals/Zend/Db/Table/Abstract.php:874
>           Zend_Db_Table_Abstract->_setupPrimaryKey()
>
> 8: /opt/psa/admin/externals/Zend/Db/Table/Abstract.php:1247
>           Zend_Db_Table_Abstract->find(string 'en-US')
>
> 9: /opt/psa/admin/plib/Db/Table/Abstract.php:97
>           Db_Table_Abstract->findOne(string 'en-US')
>
> 10: /opt/psa/admin/plib/Locale/Manager.php:195
>           Locale_Manager->_getCodes(boolean false, boolean true)
>
> 11: /opt/psa/admin/plib/Locale/Manager.php:130
>           Locale_Manager->_exists(string 'en-US', boolean true)
>
> 12: /opt/psa/admin/plib/Locale/Manager.php:153
>           Locale_Manager->isAllowed(string 'en-US')
>
> 13: /opt/psa/admin/plib/Session/Ctx/Panel.php:69
>           Plesk\Session\Ctx_Panel->_getDefault(string 'locale')
>
> 14: /opt/psa/admin/plib/Session/Ctx/Namespace.php:21
>           Plesk\Session\Ctx_Namespace->__get(string 'locale')
>
> 15: /opt/psa/admin/plib/functions.php:616
>           get_locale()
>
> 16: /opt/psa/admin/plib/modules/watchdog/localelib.php:36
>           wd__setlocale()
>
> 17: /opt/psa/libexec/modules/watchdog/cp/send-report:7
>   ERROR: Zend_Db_Statement_Exception: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1021 Disk full (/tmp/#sql_5870_0.MAI); waiting for someone to free some space... (errno: 28 "No space left on device") (Pdo.php:234)
>
> http://kb.plesk.com/plesk-error/search?metaId=4169b08ab72f0d… target='_blank'>Search for related Knowledge Base articles
>
> Попытка запуска mysqld_safe --log-error=/var/log/mysql.err
>
> 160905 10:04:58 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
>
> 160905 10:04:58 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 10.0.26-MariaDB-0+deb8u1) starting as process 1660 ...
>
> 160905 10:04:58 [Note] InnoDB: Using mutexes to ref count buffer pool pages
>
> 160905 10:04:58 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
>
> 160905 10:04:58 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
>
> 160905 10:04:58 [Note] InnoDB: Memory barrier is not used
>
> 160905 10:04:58 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.8
>
> 160905 10:04:58 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
>
> 160905 10:04:58 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
>
> 160905 10:04:58 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
>
> 160905 10:04:58 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
>
> 160905 10:04:58 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
>
> InnoDB: Transaction 21773260 was in the XA prepared state.
>
> InnoDB: 1 transaction(s) which must be rolled back or cleaned up
>
> InnoDB: in total 0 row operations to undo
>
> InnoDB: Trx id counter is 21787904
>
> InnoDB: Starting in background the rollback of uncommitted transactions
>
> 160905 10:04:58 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.
>   2016-09-05 10:04:58 7faa437ff700  InnoDB: Rollback of non-prepared transactions completed
>
> 160905 10:04:58 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
>
> 160905 10:04:58 [Note] InnoDB:  Percona XtraDB (http://www.percona.com) 5.6.30-76.3 started; log sequence number 7633460413
>
> 160905 10:04:58 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
>   2016-09-05 10:04:58 7faa61d3c780  InnoDB: Starting recovery for XA transactions...
>
> 2016-09-05 10:04:58 7faa61d3c780  InnoDB: Transaction 21773260 in prepared state after recovery
>
> 2016-09-05 10:04:58 7faa61d3c780  InnoDB: Transaction contains changes to 1 rows
>
> 2016-09-05 10:04:58 7faa61d3c780  InnoDB: 1 transactions in prepared state after recovery
>
> 160905 10:04:58 [Note] Found 1 prepared transaction(s) in InnoDB
>
> 160905 10:04:58 [ERROR] Found 1 prepared transactions! It means that mysqld was not shut down properly last time and critical recovery information
>   (last binlog or tc.log file) was manually deleted after a crash.
>   You have to start mysqld with --tc-heuristic-recover switch to commit or rollback pending transactions.
>
> 160905 10:04:58 [ERROR] Aborting
>
> 160905 10:04:58 [Note] InnoDB: FTS optimize thread exiting.
>
> 160905 10:04:58 [Note] InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
>
> 160905 10:05:01 [Note] InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 7633460423
>
> 160905 10:05:01 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete
>
> 160905 10:05:01 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid ended
>   160905 10:53:36 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
>   160905 10:53:36 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 10.0.26-MariaDB-0+deb8u1) starting as process 8183 ...
>
> 160905 10:53:36 [Note] InnoDB: Using mutexes to ref count buffer pool pages
>
> 160905 10:53:36 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
>
> 160905 10:53:36 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
>
> 160905 10:53:36 [Note] InnoDB: Memory barrier is not used
>
> 160905 10:53:36 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.8
>
> 160905 10:53:36 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
>
> 160905 10:53:36 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
>
> 160905 10:53:36 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
>
> 160905 10:53:36 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
>
> 160905 10:53:36 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
>
> InnoDB: Transaction 21773260 was in the XA prepared state.
>
> InnoDB: 1 transaction(s) which must be rolled back or cleaned up
>
> InnoDB: in total 0 row operations to undo
>
> InnoDB: Trx id counter is 21792000
>
> InnoDB: Starting in background the rollback of uncommitted transactions
>
> 2016-09-05 10:53:36 7f55273ff700  InnoDB: Rollback of non-prepared transactions completed
>
> 160905 10:53:36 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.
>
> 160905 10:53:36 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
>
> 160905 10:53:36 [Note] InnoDB:  Percona XtraDB (http://www.percona.com) 5.6.30-76.3 started; log sequence number 7633460493
>
> 160905 10:53:36 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
>
> 2016-09-05 10:53:36 7f5545acd780  InnoDB: Starting recovery for XA 
>   transactions...
>
> 2016-09-05 10:53:36 7f5545acd780  InnoDB: Transaction 21773260 in prepared state 
>   after recovery
>
> 2016-09-05 10:53:36 7f5545acd780  InnoDB: Transaction contains changes to 1 rows
>
> 2016-09-05 10:53:36 7f5545acd780  InnoDB: 1 transactions in prepared state after recovery
>
> 160905 10:53:36 [Note] Found 1 prepared transaction(s) in InnoDB
>
> 160905 10:53:36 [ERROR] Found 1 prepared transactions! It means that mysqld was not shut down properly last time and critical recovery information (last binlog or tc.log file) was manually deleted after a crash$
>
> 160905 10:53:36 [ERROR] Aborting
>
> 160905 10:53:36 [Note] InnoDB: FTS optimize thread exiting.
>
> 160905 10:53:36 [Note] InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
>
> 160905 10:53:38 [Note] InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 
>   7633460503
>
> 160905 10:53:38 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete

Вначале была мысль может действительно просто место кончилось, но посмотрев все оказалось не так, места навалом, данные терять ой как не хочется, может кто подскажет в какое место лезть ?

Comment: Может раздел /tmp ограничен и переполнился?

Comment: приложите, пожалуйста, прямо к тексту вопроса вывод двух команд: `df` и `df -i`. дополнить вопрос можно, нажав править ниже текста вопроса.

Comment: Вообщем все решилось командой `mysqld --tc-heuristic-recover=ROLLBACK`

Честно хз что оно делает но проблема пропала :)

В процессе вроде как исправлялась какая-то транзакция